# how to parse nested json using multiple from_json functions?

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

Using: https://github.com/nlohmann/json

I have a JSON I want to parse:

```
{
  "a": {
    "x": true,
    "y": false
    },
  "b": {
    "1": true,
    "2": false
    }
  }
}
```

I have 2 functions handling this:

```
typedef struct{
  std::map<std::string, bool> m;
} ConfigA;

typedef struct{
  std::map<std::string, bool> m;
} ConfigB;


void from_json(const json &j, ConfigA &c){
  j.at("a").get_to(c.m);
}
void from_json(const json &j, ConfigB &c){
  j.at("b").get_to(c.m);
}
```

What I want to do is:

1. add a member to `ConfigA` : `ConfigB b` making `ConfigA` contain `ConfigB`. This is easy enough...
2. add a line to `void from_json(const json &j, ConfigA &c)` which will
   invoke `void from_json(const json &j, ConfigB)` so I'll be able to call `ConfigA.get(json)` which will invoke the 1st `from_json` which internally will invoke the 2nd `from_json`

Is this possible?

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/nlohmann/json. I was in the middle of editing and got called away